# strncpy function not working for me correctly

Tags: c++, strncpy

I'm kind of just starting in C++ so I might have a dumb mistake here. Below is my code along with outputs in the comments. I'm using Xcode.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

 int main() {

          char myString[] = "Hello There";
          printf("%s\n", myString);

         strncpy(myString, "Over", 5); // I want this to print out "Over There"

         cout<< myString<<endl; // this prints out ONLY as "Over"

         for (int i = 0; i <11; i++){
         cout<< myString[i];
          }// I wanted to see what's going on this prints out as Over? There
          // the ? is upside down, it got added in

         cout<< endl;
         return 0;
}
```

Comment: Short answer: don't use `strncpy`. It's a function with only one real purpose, so its being of real use is quite rare. Its inclusion in the standard library is almost entirely an accident of history.

Comment: haha how interesting.... It's one of the main functions that's being used on my quizzes and exams.

Comment: Sounds like time to fire your teacher. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THE PROBLEM**

- `strncpy (destination, source, max_len)`

*strncpy* is defined to copy at most `max_len` characters from `source` to `destination`, **including** the trailing null-byte if `source` doesn't include a null-byte within the first `max_len` bytes.

In your case the trailing null-byte will be including, and with that `destination` will be null-terminated directly after `"Over"`, which is why you are seeing the described behaviour.

After your call to `strncpy` `myString` will therefore compare equal to:

```
"Over\0There"
```

---

**THE SOLUTION**

The most straight-forward solution would be to not copy the trailing null-byte from `"Over"`, which is as easy as specifying `4` instead of `5` to `strncpy`:

```
strncpy(myString, "Over", 4);
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I got it now. I feel like it's unfortunate that this string function does that. However, Jerry told me that it's rarely used so I supposed it's okay then (even if this is one of the few string functions being used alot in my class).

Comment: IMHO better style is `memcpy(myString, "Over", 4)` , as `memcpy` is a simpler function to describe than `strncpy`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I was thinking about including that in the answer, the problem with `memcpy` is that it will yield undefined-behavior if `size` happens to be greater than the actual length of `src`; `strncpy` is safer in that regard.

Comment: It's not undefined in that case (did you mean if `size` happens to be greater than the length of `src`)?    In either case we probably shouldn't be using magic numbers anyway.

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes, sorry.. stupid typo (I'm currently writing an answer to another question as we speak), I fixed my comment. Magic numbers shouldn't be used, I agree with you on that one.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for strncopy is as follows:

```
char * strncpy ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num );
```

> Copies the first num characters of source to destination. If the end
>   of the source C string (which is signaled by a null-character) is
>   found before num characters have been copied, destination is padded
>   with zeros until a total of num characters have been written to it.

By calling `strncpy(myString, "Over", 5)`, you are actually copying "Over\n" into myString.  You are probably better off calling strncpy with the last parameter as strlen(source).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

 int main() {

   char myString[] = "Hello There";
   printf("%s\n", myString);

   strncpy(myString, "Over", 4); // I want this to print out "Over There"
   strcpy( myString + 4, myString + 5 ); 

   cout<< myString<<endl; // this prints out ONLY as "Over"

   for (int i = 0; i <10; i++){
    cout<< myString[i];
   }// I wanted to see what's going on this prints out as Over? There
    // the ? is upside down, it got added in

   cout<< endl;

   return 0;
}
```